# V1 data api where clause and aggregate filters

Tags: filter, aggregate, versionone

I've been experimenting with VersionOne's data api and have come up with a query that matches the Estimate, Detail Estimate, Done (Actuals), To Do and Allocated To Do values for stories or defects that we see via the UI.  As you can see below (nl's added for legibility), I've placed filters on the aggregated values. What I am wondering is whether the where clause is needed since the aggregate filters seems to cover them. It seems to work OK with or without the where clause as it returns the same values (but it definitely doesn't work if I remove the aggregate filters). Would anyone comment on whether I'll run into some unforeseen issue if I remove the where clause?

```
Data/Story/oid-number-portion?
sel=PrimaryWorkitem.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Number,
PrimaryWorkitem.AssetState,
PrimaryWorkitem.Status.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Number,
PrimaryWorkitem.Scope.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Timebox.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Team.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Priority.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Owners.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.AssetType,
PrimaryWorkitem.Parent.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Super.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.Children,
PrimaryWorkitem.SplitTo,
PrimaryWorkitem.SplitFrom,
PrimaryWorkitem.Estimate,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChildrenMeAndDown,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChildrenMeAndDown[AssetState!='Dead','Deleted'].ToDo.@Sum,
PrimaryWorkitem.Children[AssetState!='Dead','Deleted'].ToDo.@Sum,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChildrenMeAndDown[AssetState!='Dead','Deleted'].Actuals.Value.@Sum,
PrimaryWorkitem.Children[AssetState!='Dead','Deleted'].DetailEstimate.@Sum,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChildrenMeAndDown%[AssetState!='Dead','Deleted'].AllocatedToDo.@Sum,
PrimaryWorkitem.CreateDateUTC,
PrimaryWorkitem.CreatedBy.Name,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChangeDateUTC,
PrimaryWorkitem.ChangedBy.Name
&where=(PrimaryWorkitem.AssetState!='Dead','Deleted';
        PrimaryWorkitem.ChildrenMeAndDown!='Dead','Deleted';
        PrimaryWorkitem.Children!='Dead','Deleted')
```

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, the `where` is unnecessary. It would only reduce the set of `Stories` returned and does not affect the results of relationships, like the attribute filters do. Since the start of your query includes and OID, you are just getting a single item in your result set anyway.

I see some other opportunities to improve your query. For one, the `AssetState` of `Dead` includes `Deleted` and `Template`. So you could just have `[AssetState!='Dead']`.

You might also tune your use of hierarchy navigation. For example, you are requesting both the `Children` and the `ChildrenMeAndDown` as attributes. For `Story`, the `Children` are `SecondaryWorkitems` which themselves have no `Children`. Therefore, `Story.Children` and `Story.ChildrenAndDown` return the same results. The only thing different about `Story.ChildrenMeAndDown` is that it includes the `Story` that you are already querying. So, I suspect the `Children` relationship is sufficient for all of your uses.

If you are only reading from VersionOne, have a look at the [query.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Tour_of_query.v1) endpoint. The query language is fundamentally the same, just expressed in YAML or JSON in the body of an HTTP POST. Just extrapolating from your query, you might find the subquery capability of query.v1 to be handy.